# php form with list box is not working ?

Tags: php, html, mysql

In the below code the list box is getting populated with the values but when I select the corresponding list value and click search the table is not getting displayed. I have used the SELF_PHP for the form action here also the idea of this form is that the list will be having and id's populated while the loading of the page. When I select a list value and click on the search button it should display the table with the values of only that ambulance ID or id which has been selected in the list box. Please help me.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
             <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>TPS Login Page</title>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            </head>
            <body>  
            <center>
            <h2>Ambulance Activity Log</h2>
            <hr>
             <form name="search" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

             View activity of ambulance:   
             <Select NAME="field">
              <?php 
                include 'con.php';
                $query = "SELECT amb_id FROM ambulance;";
                $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to retreive amb_id :".mysql_error()); 

                if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
                {
                  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
                  {
                    echo"<option id=\"ambid\" value=$row[amb_id]>$row[amb_id]</option>";
                  }
                }
              ?>
             </Select>
             <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
             <input type="hidden" name="searching" value="yes" />

             </form>

            <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
            {
                $id=getElementById('ambid') ;

                $query = "SELECT * FROM log WHERE amb_id='$id' ORDER BY l_time DESC;";
                $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
                print " 
                <table border=\"5\" cellpadding=\"5\" cellspacing=\"0\" style=\"border-collapse: collapse\" bordercolor=\"#808080\" width=\"800\" text-align=\"center\" id=\"AutoNumber2\" bgcolor=\"#C0C0C0\">
                <tr>            
                <td width=\"30\">Amb ID</td> 
                <td width=\"120\">Event Time</td> 
                <td width=\"50\">Description</td> 
                <td width=\"30\">Signal ID</td> 
                <td width=\"30\">Road No</td> 
                <td width=\"30\">Priority</td> 
                </tr>"; 

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
                { 
                print "<tr>"; 
                print "<td>" . $row['amb_id'] . "</td>"; 
                print "<td>" . $row['l_time'] . "</td>"; 
                print "<td>" . $row['l_event'] . "</td>";
                print "<td>" . $row['t_sigid'] . "</td>";
                print "<td>" . $row['l_roadno'] . "</td>";
                print "<td>" . $row['e_priority'] . "</td>";

                print "</tr>"; 
                } 
                print "</table>"; 
                print "</center>";
            }
            ?>
           </body>
            </html>
```

Please help me.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you checked the HTML you're generating to make sure it's correct?

Comment: getElementById() is not a php function, it should be `$_GET['field']` also you have sql injection and XSS when using PHP_SELF

Comment: You shouldn't have multiple elements with same `id`

Comment: you mixed javascript(getElementById) with php code. also you try to display and handle the form post in the same file. it's better to use 2 files for this.

Comment: HTML was very lengthy so while posting it I deleted some part of the code.
I'm not bothered about SQL injection as i'm working on the academic project.

Comment: @Aris I tried with $_POST[] it didn't worked so I tried using getelementbyid. I found it in stackoverflow only but didn't helped. So the final option I have is to use the separate files I guess. 
Thanks anyways for the quick reply.

Comment: for sure separate files( form -> processing ) will help you in debugging.

Comment: Have you seen my 2 answers ? Wy no response ?

Answer (score 0):

Give the `<select>` Tag a better name . And quote your `"$row[amb_id]"`.  `value=$row[amb_id]` ! is wrong.

```
<select name="ambid" size="10">
....

              {
                echo"<option value=\"$row[amb_id]\">$row[amb_id]</option>";
              }
 </select>
```

After post you can get it with :

```
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {
     $id=$_POST['ambid'];
     $query = "...
```

Comment: Please, please, PLEASE don't suggest to people that they include SQL injection holes in their code...

Comment: @Adrian : I know I read it a hundred times a day. It's OP's choice. And it looks like it is not yet production development.

Comment: Yes, but if we're going to provide example code, we shouldn't encourage people to write something broken... bad examples breed bad code and uninformed/misinformed developers, good examples do the opposite. If we could replace all the "tutorials" and "samples" that use mysql_* with mysqli or PDO, we'd see about 90% fewer people using them, just because so many people learn from examples they found "somewhere online".

Comment: @Adrian Bro chill .
This is an academic project only.